# SonarQube only reachable with internal ip not external

Tags: networking, nginx, sonarqube, hyper-v, sonarqube-ops

We have an hyper-v machine in our DMZ with an Ubuntu machine on it. SonarQube is installed on the VM. When we try to access it from inside the network by IP there is nothing wrong and it works fine. We have setup a firewall route to forward all traffic from the internet to the VM. The forwarder as we setup is correct as we used it multiple times with other servers and works fine. The VM has 1 NIC with the internal IP on it. Is there something we are missing? If you need any more information please let me know. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: which version of SonarQube ?

Comment: did you try to configure the property sonar.web.host documented in conf/sonar.properties ?

Comment: Usual troubleshooting questions: can you ping the VM from the internet ? can you ping the VM from firewall ? from the Internet do you see HTTP requests passing through your firewall ? do you see them hitting SonarQube ? (`logs/acces.log`) Which error are you getting in the browser ?

Comment: We are running the latest version of SonarQube. Also it is possible to ping from external to the vm if i ping the external ip from the machine. internal ping also possible and ping from vm to internet aswell. the sonar.web.host is setup as 127.0.0.1 and the sonar.web.port is setup as 9100. the http request is passing the firewall we have put a monitoring on it. on the access.log is nothing strange to see i only see the internal requests in it.

Comment: You mention 'internal requests': are these requests coming from the VM itself or from other machines in the same network ? which URL do these requests target ? (share screenshots if needed) is there a reverse proxy running on the SonarQube VM ?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue.
In the hosts file there was no local host setup.
From internal we connected by ip so there was no issue. The files were setup to connect to localhost so it did not know where to go. thanks for the support.